# Его глаза выро(а)внялись с моими

Tags: грамотная-речь

Какой корень следует писать в данном случае?

*Его глаза выро(а)внялись с моими.*

Comment: Не очень понятен контекст.

Comment: Скорее всего, проблема не в букве, а в сочетаемости слов.

Comment: Если закрыть глаза на сочетаемость (трудно судить о состоянии своих глаз со стороны; возможно, всё это видят на мониторе), то с буквой "а" его глаза стали совпадать с собственными по размеру, а с буквой "о" - оказались на том же воображаемом уровне.

Comment: Для спорного слова надо бы подыскать нужную, взамен имеющейся, приставку. Выбор есть на любой случай, в т. ч. и отражения в мониторе.

Comment: А не поменять ли на " он поднял на меня глаза", Или "он заглянул мне в глаза"? Извините, если это не подходит по смыслу.

Answer (score 2):

Трудно представить контекст, но из всех значений глагола выровняться здесь подходит "встать на одной прямой, на одном уровне". Малый академический словарь:

> выровняться
> -яюсь, -яешься; сов. (несов. выравниваться).
>
> 1. Стать ровным, гладким. Лед на катке выровнялся.
> 2. Выпрямиться в горизонтальной или вертикальной плоскости, расположиться по прямой. Бомбардировщик делает несколько попыток
>    выровняться, --- добивается на несколько секунд горизонтального
>    полета, но вновь теряет управление. А. Н. Толстой, Таран. И вдруг
>    застучал мотор. --- Сейнер мгновенно выровнялся и стал тяжело
>    взбираться на набежавшую волну. Чаковский, У нас уже утро.
> 3. Расположиться в ряд (ряды) по прямой линии. Гул разговоров стоял в оживившихся и выровнявшихся рядах. Куприн, Ночлег. Роты без взаимного
>    сговора подтянулись, выровнялись в рядах. Первенцев, Огненная земля.
> 4. Вырастая, выправиться, развиться физически. Первое время она была очень слаба, тщедушна и собой некрасива, но понемногу справилась и
>    выровнялась, а месяцев через восемь --- превратилась в очень ладную
>    собачку. Тургенев, Муму. Выровнялась Дуняшка в статную и по-своему
>    красивую девку. Шолохов, Тихий Дон. ||
>
> Стать ровным, спокойным, приобрести уравновешенность. Характер
> выровнялся. □ Отношения его с Пьером Корнелем давно уже выровнялись
> после ссоры. Булгаков, Жизнь господина де Мольера.

https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/mas/8005/%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F

Следовательно, корень -ровн- **выровняться** , но  вы**равн**иваться (несов.вид)

Answer (score 2):

Правильно: *Его глаза **выровнялись** с моими.*

Чтобы ответить на этот вопрос, достаточно различать понятия "равный" и "ровный".

Глаза не могут быть равны друг другу (они не одинаковые),  но могут находиться на одинаковом **уровне**, в одной плоскости. А это семантика **ровной поверхности**.

РОВНЫЙ,  1. Гладкий и плоский, без впадин и возвышений. Р-ая местность. Р-ая, как скатерть, дорога.  Р. пол.

ВЫРОВНЯТЬСЯ, св. 1. только 3 л. Стать ровным, плоским, гладким. Лёд на катке выровнялся.

Примеры:

(1) Доцент дважды промазал, а лейтенант забил четверку с шестеркой, и счет почти **выравнялся.**

(2) Щенок и заяц подросли и **выровнялись**, привыкли друг к другу и презабавно играли.

Тогда он нажал чашку, ушедшую вниз, и весы почему-то **выровнялись**.