# "Выр(а/о)внять самолёт": зависит ли выбор буквы от контекста?

Tags: орфография, выбор-слов, семантика, корень-слова, чередования

Скажите, в предложении "Затем пилот сделал несколько попыток выр(а/о)внять самолёт" какой глагол употребляется: *вырАвнять* или *вырОвнять*? Я затрудняюсь понять разницу, зависит от контекста? С одной стороны, если цель — чтобы он летел рОвно, в каком-то смысле "гладко" (прямо, без крена, по курсу), правильно: *вырОвнять,* а с другой, если цель — чтобы он летел нарАвне с другими самолётами (одинаково, на одном уровне, в линию), правильно: *вырАвнять*? Или наоборот?

Подобную тему поднимали [здесь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/461229/%D0%95%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C-%D1%81-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8), но яснее не стало (хоть убейте, не понимаю, как можно вырОвнять глаза)...

**ДОПОЛНЕНО (17.05.2022)**

"Грамота.ру" в итоге ответила, что правильно: *вырОвнять самолёт* (см. [Грамоту.ру](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=309630)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Затем пилот сделал несколько попыток выр**о**внять самолёт.*

Большой толковый словарь ([Грамота.ру](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic?word=%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C&all=x)):

> **ВЫРОВНЯТЬ,** -яю, -яешь; ***св.*** (***нсв.*** также **ровнять**). *кого-что.* <...> **2.** *что.* Расположить, направить по прямой линии в вертикальной или горизонтальной плоскости. *В. самолёт.*

Даже если "цель — чтобы он летел нарАвне с другими самолётами (одинаково, на одном уровне, в линию)", глагол *выр**а**внять* (сделать равным) не подойдёт. Словосочетание *выр**а**внять самолёт* (что звучит грубо и слишком абстрактно) можно использовать, скорее, в контексте изменения каких-либо технических характеристик самолёта, для того чтобы он стал "одинаковым" по отношению к другим своим собратьям.
В нашем же случае самолёт должен расположиться в одном ряду или в одной плоскости с другими. Это же касается и глаз, на вопрос о которых даётся ссылка. В том примере глаза мы не делаем ни р**о**вными, ни р**а**вными, мы их выравниваем с другими, ставим на одном уровне.

На буквы А и О в однокоренных словах (*нар**а**вне, ур**о**вень* и пр.) опираться не стоит, так как имеет место чередование гласных в корнях ***ровн/равн***, а есть и исключения, например *р**а**внина* (относительно р**о**вная поверхность).

Выбор зависит только от смысла высказывания.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136290/discussion-on-answer-by--------).